# How to generate multiple Dropdown dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a Java background and new to Flutter. I have stuck in a scenario where I need to create multiple dropdown dynamically. For instance, There is a Pizza deal offers 2 Large pizza, 2 Small pizza and 1 drink. So, Whenever customer select any pizza He/She must need to select a flavor to it. If there is 2 Large pizza what i need to generate is 2 dropdown list with defined flavor so that customer can select 2 different flavor and want to save them in separate variable so that, I can get the value later on, and the same goes for 2 small pizza. In this deal, I have to create 5 dropdown and the quantity of dropdown varies along the deal they offer. How can I achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 4):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `ListView`, when add data to `List` like `List<CartItem>`, `DropdownButton` will show 
You can for loop `List<CartItem>` to summary data you need like quantity

code snippet

```
class _CartWidgetState extends State<CartWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Pizza(cartItem: widget.cart[widget.index])),
        Expanded(child: Flavor(cartItem: widget.cart[widget.index])),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                print(widget.index);
                widget.cart.removeAt(widget.index);
                widget.callback();
              });
...           
ListView.builder(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  itemCount: cart.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return CartWidget(
                        cart: cart, index: index, callback: refresh);
                  }),
```

output of working demo when click `print button`

```
I/flutter (14508): Pizza 1
I/flutter (14508): Pizza 2
I/flutter (14508): Pizza 4
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Flavor extends StatefulWidget {
  CartItem cartItem;

  Flavor({this.cartItem});
  @override
  _FlavorState createState() => _FlavorState();
}

class _FlavorState extends State<Flavor> {
  String _value = "Flavor 1";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.cartItem.flavor;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Flavor oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.cartItem.flavor != widget.cartItem.flavor) {
      _value = widget.cartItem.flavor;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButton(
          value: _value,
          items: [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text("Flavor 1"),
              value: "Flavor 1",
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text("Flavor 2"),
              value: "Flavor 2",
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Flavor 3"), value: "Flavor 3"),
            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Flavor 4"), value: "Flavor 4")
          ],
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;
              widget.cartItem.flavor = value;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}

class Pizza extends StatefulWidget {
  CartItem cartItem;

  Pizza({this.cartItem});
  @override
  _PizzaState createState() => _PizzaState();
}

class _PizzaState extends State<Pizza> {
  String _value = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.cartItem.itemName;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Pizza oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.cartItem.itemName != widget.cartItem.itemName) {
      _value = widget.cartItem.itemName;
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButton(
          value: _value,
          items: [
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text("Pizza 1"),
              value: "Pizza 1",
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text("Pizza 2"),
              value: "Pizza 2",
            ),
            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Pizza 3"), value: "Pizza 3"),
            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Pizza 4"), value: "Pizza 4")
          ],
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _value = value;
              widget.cartItem.itemName = value;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class CartItem {
  String productType;
  String itemName;
  String flavor;
  CartItem({this.productType, this.itemName, this.flavor});
}

class CartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CartItem> cart;
  int index;
  VoidCallback callback;

  CartWidget({this.cart, this.index, this.callback});
  @override
  _CartWidgetState createState() => _CartWidgetState();
}

class _CartWidgetState extends State<CartWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Pizza(cartItem: widget.cart[widget.index])),
        Expanded(child: Flavor(cartItem: widget.cart[widget.index])),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                print(widget.index);
                widget.cart.removeAt(widget.index);
                widget.callback();
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<CartItem> cart = [];

  void refresh() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  itemCount: cart.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return CartWidget(
                        cart: cart, index: index, callback: refresh);
                  }),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    cart.add(CartItem(
                        productType: "pizza",
                        itemName: "Pizza 1",
                        flavor: "Flavor 1"));
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Text("add Pizza"),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                      print(cart[i].itemName);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("Print Pizza"),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I only want the selected data from a particular dropdown instead of printing a list?

Comment: You can use cart[index].attribue,  like cart[2].itemName or cart[3].flavor

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collection-if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) in your UI code to show those dropdowns when a certain condition is met.

```
Widget build() {
  return Column(
    children: [
      pizzaSelector(),
      if (pizzaIsSelected)
      flavorSelector(),
    ]
  );
}
```

[Andrea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnaN_6465Gk) has a good video explaining collection-if and spread operators which I think will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response but what i have to done first is to generate multiple dropdown. Tell me if i want to generate 'n' dropdown programmatically in flutter and get each selected value in a different variable. How can i do this?

Comment: To generate 'n' dropdowns, you can use a collection-for. Check out the video and link above. As for saving the selected values, I think that should be handled away from the UI code, in a class/object. You would have a standard pizza/flavor selector which saves an instance of Pizza, and you would create it 'n' times based on the deal.