# How to generate multiple Dropdown dynamically in Flutter using Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

Referring to this [How to generate multiple Dropdown dynamically in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63185974/15160329)
How can we implement the answer using Provider, not setState

I tried implementing it but it's giving following error:

**The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#766ba](state: RawGestureDetectorState#a1e19(gestures: , behavior: opaque)):**

**dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<EventsProvider?>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _DivisionDropDownButtonState.initState() completed.**

Comment: could you please share your full code in above question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's actually resolved, I was not calling notifyListeners();

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.